# Magento 2 - get list of all manufacturers in a category

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation

I am trying to get a list of all manufactures (brands) in my block for the current category. (Essentially the "Brands" filter in the layered navigation). This is my current code:

```
<?php
namespace Sulman\Brands\Block;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getBrands()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $categoryId = 3;

        $resource = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();

        $select = $connection->select()->from(['ea' => $connection->getTableName('eav_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id')
            ->join(['eea' => $connection->getTableName('eav_entity_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id = eea.attribute_id')
            ->join(['cea' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_eav_attribute')], 'ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id')
            ->join(['cpe' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity')], 'eea.attribute_set_id = cpe.attribute_set_id')
            ->join(['ccp' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_category_product')], 'cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id')
            ->where('cea.is_filterable = ?', 1)
            ->where('ccp.category_id = ?', $categoryId)
            ->group('ea.attribute_id');

        $attributeIds = $connection->fetchCol($select);
        // attributeIds is empty.
        foreach ($attributeIds as $filter){
            echo "x";
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this with the help of this post:
https://magecom.wordpress.com/2016/06/21/get-layer-filter-and-available-options/

```
<?php
namespace Sulman\Brands\Block;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getBrands()
    {
        $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');//get current category
        $layer = $this->_layerResolver->get();
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category->getId());

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $fill = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList');
        $filterList = new \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList($objectManager,$fill);
        $filterAttributes = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
        $j = 0;
        foreach($filterAttributes as $filter){
            if($filter->getName() == 'Brand'){
                $items = $filter->getItems();
                foreach($items as $item)
                {
                    $filterValues[$j]['display'] = strip_tags($item->getLabel());
                    $filterValues[$j]['label'] = $item->getValue();
                    $filterValues[$j]['count'] = $item->getCount(); //Gives no. of products in each filter options
                    $filterValues[$j]['image'] = $this->getBrandImage(strip_tags($item->getLabel()));
                    $j++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $filterValues;
    }

    private function getBrandImage($label){
        $mediaDir = $this->getUrl('pub/media');
        $lcase = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $label));
        return $mediaDir."brands/".$lcase.".jpg";
    }
}
```