# How to add lists brand under footer

Tags: magento2, layout, template, footer

I want to add brands list under footer:
[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<container name="after-footer-container" label="after footer container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="brands-after-footer" after="footer-container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="brands-collection" template="Magento_Theme::html/brands-footer.phtml" />
</container>
```

You put your brands content in : `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themeName}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/brands-footer.phtml`

Comment: And from here you can add code to brands-footer.phtml https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183815/magento-2-get-list-of-all-manufacturers-in-a-category